# Share single string via Apache 2

Tags: apache, http

Is it possible to have a Apache 2 server that shares only one string - "Hello World!" ? 
I want to use GET request and get only "Hello World!" from the server. How can I do this ?

Comment: what have you tried? do you not want to use an `index.html` file?

Comment: @raam86 After GET request I just want to get raw string nothing more.

Comment: you can put a raw string in index.html, your question doesn't make a lot of sense, do you mean you want the content-type to be `text/plain`?

Comment: @raam86 Ok it's working. I just changed content of index.html to "Hello world". Thank you !

Comment: If the answer worked for you, you can mark it as chosen answer

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply change the content of `index.html` in your `www` folder to be `Hello World`